# Using Powershell to list Email distribution group name, member count and email address then export to .CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server, windows-scripting

I need to get the Exchange Distribution group that has member less than or equal to 1.

The output that I need is as .CSV:

```
Distributionlistname , membercount , EmailAddress
DLName1, 1, DL1@domain.com
DLName2, 0, DL2@domain.com
DLName3, 0, DL3@domain.com
...
```

This is the script that I have found but doesn't give me the output like the above:

```
Get-DistributionGroup –ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object { (Get-DistributionGroupMember –identity $_.Name –ResultSize Unlimited).Count -lt 1 } | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty EmailAddresses | Export-Csv C:\Result.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way (keeps the idea of an one-liner):

```
Get-DistributionGroup –ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object { (Get-DistributionGroupMember –identity $_.Name –ResultSize Unlimited).Count -lt 1 } | Select-Object Name,@{Name="EmailAddress";Expression={(Get-DistributionGroupMember –identity $_.Name –ResultSize Unlimited).Count}},PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-Csv C:\Result.csv
```

Though, this is problay not super efficient because you run `Get-DistributionGroupMember` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Paxz :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$result = @()
Get-DistributionGroup –ResultSize Unlimited | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $memberCount = @(Get-DistributionGroupMember –Identity $_.DistinguishedName –ResultSize Unlimited).Count
        if ($memberCount -le 1) {
            $result += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                'DistributionlistName' = $_.Name
                'MemberCount'          = $memberCount
                'EmailAddress'         = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
            }
        }
    }

$result | Export-Csv C:\Result.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```